# Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError - type: OAuthException, code: 2500, message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth, koala-gem

I am trying to setup a project. Everything has gone fine but this error keeps prompting up and nothing seems to help. Here is the log when i hit the url.

```
Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError - type: OAuthException, code: 2500, message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. [HTTP 400]:
koala (2.2.0) lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:515:in `block in graph_call'
koala (2.2.0) lib/koala/api.rb:80:in `api'
koala (2.2.0) lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:513:in `graph_call'
koala (2.2.0) lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:115:in `get_connection'
() home/yogesh/Desktop/jugojuice/jugojuice/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:98:in `show'
() home/yogesh/Desktop/jugojuice/jugojuice/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:64:in `home'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:308:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
() home/yogesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/route_translator-f00b46885426/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:20:in `set_locale_from_url'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:307:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
xray-rails (0.1.16) lib/xray/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
 () home/yogesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 () home/yogesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 () home/yogesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
logging (1.8.2) lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `block in create_with_logging_context'



Started POST "/__better_errors/329b87011a8e5497/variables" for ::1 at 2015-11-18 16:48:21 +0530
```

My code in pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

layout :determine_layout
before_filter :cms_setup, :only => [:show,  :sitemap, :search]
before_filter :set_locale
helper_method :transformed_content

def parse_facebook_cookies
@facebook_cookies = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new.get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)
end

def sitemap
@page = Page.friendly.find("sitemap")
@subnav_pages = nil
end

def search
@page = Page.friendly.find("search")
@section = @page
@pages=Page.nested_set
@search = Sunspot.search([Cms::Page, Cms::Asset, Product, City, Location]) do
  fulltext  params[:terms] do
    fields  "title_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym, "content_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym, "description_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym, "address_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym
  end
end
@results = @search.results
end

def cms_update
page = Page.find(params[:id])
region = Cms::Region.find(params[:region_id])
asset =  Cms::Asset.find(params[:asset_id]) if params[:asset_id] && !params[:asset_id].blank?
# Update page
if asset
  #asset.update_column(:content,  params[:content])
  if asset.content != params[:content]
    asset.content = params[:content]
    asset.save!
  end
  expire_fragment(["page_#{page.id}_region_#{region.id}_asset_#{asset.id}"])
  else
  asset = Cms::Asset.new(:content => params[:content], :name => "#{page.title} - #{region.name}")
  asset.save
  end

pra = Cms::PageRegionAsset.find_or_initialize_by(page_id: page.id, region_id: region.id, asset_id: asset.id) unless asset.nil?

unless params[:content].blank?
  pra.save!
end

render text: ""
end


def home
response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
@page = Page.root
get_site_pages
get_main_nav
get_subnav
@slides = Slide.visible.in_order
@newsletter_signup = NewsletterSignup.new
show
render "show"
end

def show
response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
if @page.redirect_page_id.nil?
  #get page template and regions
  @template = @page.template
  @regions = @template.regions
  if @page.product_lines.any?
    @product_line = @page.product_lines.first
  end
  if is_editing?
    @page_content = HashWithIndifferentAccess[:regions => @regions.map { |r| {:placeholder => r.placeholder, :name => r.name, :id => r.id, :assets => r.serialized_assets_for(@page)}}.flatten]
  else
    @page_content = HashWithIndifferentAccess[:regions => @regions.map { |r|
                                                {:placeholder => r.placeholder, :name => r.name, :id => r.id, :assets => r.serialized_assets_for(@page)}
                                              }.flatten]
  end
  @cms_assets = @page.page_region_assets.order(position: :asc)
else
  unless @page.redirect_page_id.nil?
    @page = Page.find(@page.redirect_page_id)
    redirect_to @page.menu_url and return
  end
end
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("2502342425320", {:count => 4})
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("15239926112542342322478", "fc960a1a044492431aer35qafsd44a42c9c47990ef9b", "http://localhost:3000/")
@authtoken = @oauth.get_app_access_token
# generate authenticating URL
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new("1523992323611252478|1iBWrcRsYSBsISfsyUoNSmm_opxrI")
# @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
# @profile = @graph.get_object("me")
@feed = @graph.get_connections("me", "feed")
end

def render_404
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", :layout => false, :status => :not_found }
  format.xml  { head :not_found }
  format.any  { head :not_found }
end
end

private
def determine_layout
@page.template.file_name
end

def get_main_nav
@main_nav_items = Page.main_nav
end

def get_subnav
@subnav_pages = @page.subnav_pages
end

def get_site_pages
@site_pages = Page.nested_set.visible
end

def cms_setup
#render text: params.inspect and return
if params[:path].nil?
  @page = Page.root
else
  @page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:id]) if params[:id]
  @page ||= Page.friendly.find(params[:path]) if params[:path]
  @page ||= Page.root unless params[:path]
  @page ||= Page.find_by(slug: params[:path].match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]) if params[:path]
  @page ||= Page.find_by_slug("404")
  if @page.nil?
    #render text: params.inspect and return
    render_404 and return
    #page_not_found
    redirect_to "/404" and return
  end
end
@section = @page if @page.depth == 1
@section ||= @page.ancestors.select{|p| p.depth == 1}.first if @page.depth > 1
get_main_nav
get_subnav
end

def transformed_content(content)
frag = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(content) #this gets us the regions content in a nodset
snippets = frag.css("div.cms-snippet")
dynamic_snippets = frag.xpath('descendant::div[@data-snippettype="dynamic"]')
dynamic_snippets.each do |ds|
  object_class = ds.xpath("@data-objectclass")
  object_id = ds.xpath("@data-objectid").first.value
  snippet_partial = "/#{object_class.to_s.pluralize}/instance.html.haml"
  ds.content = "" #zero out the content and replace it with a rendered partial
  ds << (raw render :partial => snippet_partial, :locals => {:object_id => object_id}).to_s
end
frag
end

def page_params
params.require(:page).permit!
end

def page_not_found
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end

def set_locale
unless request.path.include?("/api")
  @locale = params[:locale]
  @locale ||= cookies[:locale]
  @locale ||= I18n.default_locale

  I18n.locale = @locale


  if params[:locale].blank?
    if cookies[:locale].blank?
      redirect_to "/#{I18n.default_locale.to_s}#{request.path_info}" unless request.path.include?("/admin")
    else
      redirect_to "/#{cookies[:locale].to_s}#{request.path_info}" unless request.path.include?("/admin")
    end
  end
  cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale
  if request.path.include?("/admin")
    I18n.locale = :en
  end
  end
  end
  end
```

I will be really thankful if someone tells me what is wrong here.

Comment: Your error is right there: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

So make sure your Facebook Graph API access token is set up properly and up to date as described here: https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala I have given the code of pages_controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @techdreams has commented, the error is the access token you're using, is invalid. Looking at your code seems you're getting the access token from a cookie. Just please keep in mind that an access token can become invalid if the user logs out of facebook or changes his/her password so you have always to implement a "refresh token" in your App, which basically is prompt the login dialog again to get a new token. If user has already approved your App this process will be transparent to him/her and they won't see the dialog again.